# Learning a union of intervals

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Suppose I have `N` one-dimensional points `xi` and their labels `yi = 1/0`.  I would like to learn a set of `k` intervals such that, when label 1 is given to all the points in those intervals, error is minimized.  i.e. if a dataset was:

```
1: 0
2: 0
3: 1
4: 1
5: 0
6: 1
7: 1
8: 1
9: 0
10: 0
11: 0
```

with `k=1`, then the best interval would be `[3, 8]`.  It gets a little more complicated as `k` increases.

Is there some common algorithm for doing this in scikit-learn, or some modification of the decision tree algorithm?  Just the straight up decision tree algorithm would not work because you can't control for `k`, only for depth, and the order in which branches are made could lead to a sub-optimal final set of intervals.  Something that's not in scikit-learn would probably be ok as well if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can restate this as an integer programming problem.

Let:

```
x_ij = 1 if interval i's left endpoint is at j
       0 otherwise
```

and:

```
y_ij = 1 if interval i's right endpoint is at j
       0 otherwise
```

and finally:

```
a_k = Total # of 1's in the interval [0, k]
b_k = Total # of 0's in the interval [0, k]
```

Then the following is equivalent to your problem:

```
maximize sum_ijk (   a_j * y_ij - a_k - x_ik     # Ones inside 
                   - b_j * y_ij - b_k - x_ik     # Zeros inside
                   + b_j * x_ij - b_k - y_(i-1)k # Zeros outside
                   - a_j * x_ij - a_k - y_(i-1)k # Ones outside
         )
with respect to the constraints
    sum_j x_ij = 1 for each i
    sum_j y_ij = 1 for each i
    0 <= x_ij <= 1 for each i, j
    0 <= y_ij <= 1 for each i, j
    sum_j * y_ij - j * x_ij > 0 for each i
    sum_j * x_(i+1)j - j * y_ij > 0 for each i
```

With the constraints that each `x_ij` and `y_ij` are integers, it's an integer programming problem.  Lifting this constraint, you have a linear programming problem, though the result in this case is hard to interpret.

For:

```
maximize sum_ijk ( a_j * y_ij - a_k - x_ik )
```

The sum over `i` is all the intervals.  Each term `a_j * y_ij` is "on" for only one value of j, the right endpoint of that interval.  The same with `a_j * x_ij`.  Then the difference is some `a_k - a_r`, which is the total number of 1's in the interval.  Similarly, the other three terms count occurrences of correct and incorrect classification.

For the constraints:

```
sum_j x_ij = 1 for each i
sum_j y_ij = 1 for each i
```

say that the intervals must have one left and one right endpoint each, and

```
sum j * y_ij - j * x_ij > 0 for each i
sum j * x_(i+1)j - j * y_ij > 0 for each i
```

says that the left endpoint must be to the left of the right endpoint, and the right endpoint of the `i+1`st interval must be to the left of the right endpoint of the `i`th interval.

Comment: Hmmm... well, I like this idea, but it would be linear programming, and the objective function would need to be representative of misclassification error rather than total number of 1s correctly classified.  Otherwise you could just say [-infinity, infinity] for every interval to get all the 1s every time, right?

Comment: Yah!  I thought of that while making dinner!  You could easily change it to the number of ones inside + number of zeros outside - the number of zeros inside - number of ones outside though, which is proportional to the misclassification rate.

Comment: I tried to fix up the statement of the objective function to reflect that.